# Power BI - formatting matrix table column headers

Tags: powerbi, formatting

Team,
Is it possible to format the column headers on a matrix table to appear at the bottom instead of the top?  So instead, the values (remote, possible, likely) would appear on the bottom like a chart?

[image]

Comment: I am 95% sure this it not possible..

Comment: I've been digging through various sites and Google searches ... I'm in agreement with you.  I haven't found anything but wanted to take a shot and see if someone had a trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this little work around:

1. Make the Column Header text white so that it doesn't appear on the page.
2. Make text boxes for each column and put them on the bottom of the matrix.